# Copy polyline from 2D to 3D?

Tags: layers, arcgis-pro, 3d-map

On the right is a single row feature class polylineZ (with elev data) displayed on a new 2D map with no base map.

On the left is that same feature copied (using drag from contents pane) to a new 3D scene with no base map.

Why does the 3D look radically different? What factors would vary the image after copying from 2D to 3D? or is it something else I'm missing?

All I want is the feature to match. I am not groot. I am noob.

ArcGIS Pro v2.1.3

[image: Copy polyline 2D to 3D]

Comment: It might make more sense if you add a basemap. You can see the angle that you're looking at the data. With the 2D map, you're looking straight down. With the 3D scene, you could be looking at an angle, or horizontally at the data.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried all that. But for the purposed of the question, I've created a clean slate to keep the contributing factors down to a minimum.

Comment: Just so we can give a consistent answer, can you upload that as a layer package or a pro package somewhere so we can replicate?

Comment: Here is the pro package:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6F3l4UfOiIuOd3Bp0rzYkBzLBc_-lOq/view?usp=sharing